# Makefile dependencies help Java

Tags: java, makefile

so I am not the best at Makefiles. I'm sort of new and trying to learn how the targets and dependencies work and such. Basically, here is my my Makefile now:

```
SRC=src/
BIN=bin/
PPWD=../
JC=javac
JC_FLAGS=
JVM=java
JVM_FLAGS= -classpath $(BIN)
BINARY=NuText
RM_FLAGS=rm -rf

default: $(SRC)*.java
    $(JC) $(JC_FLAGS) $(SRC)*.java
    mv $(SRC)*.class $(BIN)

new: clean default

run: new
    $(JVM) $(JVM_FLAGS) $(BINARY)

clean:
    $(RM_FLAGS) $(BIN)*.class
```

The problem is that when I want to run my program, it compiles every single time I use `make run`, when I only want it to compile if the `.class` files that I want to run are older than the `.java` files in the `src/` directory. How can I set my my dependencies so it will only compile the program (i.e. use the `new` target) if there is a `.java` file that is more recent than the `.class` file in `bin/`? Thanks for your help!

Edit: Thanks Etan and Joe for the help! I got it working by editing it to the following:

```
SRC=src/
BIN=bin/
JC=javac
JC_FLAGS=
JVM=java
JVM_FLAGS= -classpath $(BIN)
BINARY=NuText
RM_FLAGS=rm -rf

default: $(SRC)*.java
    $(JC) $(JC_FLAGS) $(SRC)*.java
    mv $(SRC)*.class $(BIN)

new: clean default

run: $(BIN)$(BINARY).class
    $(JVM) $(JVM_FLAGS) $(BINARY)

$(BIN)$(BINARY).class: $(SRC)*.java
    make new

clean:
    $(RM_FLAGS) $(BIN)*.class
```

Comment: make determines whether to run a given recipe based on whether the target file (left-hand side of `:`) exists and is newer than the prerequisite files (right-hand side of `:`). Your rules are all using "names" and not files (and don't create files with those names) so make can never tell it doesn't need to do the work.

Comment: Plus, `run` invokes `new`, which then invokes `clean`, which wipes out all previous work.

Comment: The `default` target uses the java files, and that's why I was thinking it would work. But it still compiles every time. I cannot figure out how to only compile if the `.class` files are older than the `.java` files.

Comment: Noooo, why Make for Java?  (Rather than a modern build system designed for the purpose)

Comment: Java does not work well with make.  You should use something else.  Make is targeted at an environment where an output file is generated by invoking a tool (like a compiler) on a set of input files.  In general, the names of the output and at least one of the input files are related (such as compiling `foo.c` into `foo.o`, etc.)  Java is very different, where "compiling" a `.java` file generates a number of output files, where the names rarely match up with the input file names.  This really requires a tool that can parse Java files, which make doesn't do.